# Cleaning Excel Spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have what seems to be a simple task - I am almost done, but have one pesky issue I should be able to get rid of, but it's being elusive.

I have a number of Excel .xls files. The file name is in the format .xls.  I created the filenames.txt file to iterate through to get the company names.
Each file has garbage data in the first 4 or so rows, so I need to remove those first four rows in all the files. I then need to add a column with the  in the first column position.

My code runs with no errors, but the output is not exactly what I need.
The only problems I am running into are:
1. I am getting a leading column added that I wasn't expecting with index numbers.
2. The strip command doesn't appear to be stripping the '.xls' - so what ends up being inserted into the column in Excel is .xls instead of just .
3. Because the '.xls' is not being stripped properly, the to_excel command is saving the file with a '.xls.xls' extension.

I read a few similar scenarios, so I have this code being used:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = os.chdir(r"C:\Users\mheitz\Documents\testing")

filenames = [names.strip('\n') for names in \            
    open(r"C:\Users\mheitz\Documents\testing\filenames.txt",'r').readlines()]

for name in filenames:
    vendors = pd.read_excel(name, header = 11, skiprows =0-10)
    vendors.insert(0,'Vendor Name',(name[:-4]))
    vendors.to_excel(r"C:\Users\mheitz\Documents\testing\clean\clean" + name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

exhibit_company = [i.strip('\n')[:-4] for names in \
                  open('filenames.txt','r').readlines()]

for company in exhibit_company:
    vendors = pd.read_excel(company, header = 5, skiprows =0-4)
    vendors.insert(0,'Vendor Name',(company))
    vendors.to_excel('/Users/michaelheitz/Desktop/Work 
                     Stuff/Data/clean'+company+'.xls')
```

Explanation:

```
open('filenames.txt', 'r').readlines() 
['james.xls\n', 'nancy.xls\n', 'temitope.xls\n', 'bianca.xls\n']
```

To remove \n , we use strip('\n').

```
for name in names:
        name.strip('\n')
    james.xls
    nancy.xls
    temitope.xls
    bianca.xls
```

To remove .xls, we use [:-4], because len(.xls) = 4, using negative means
slice after 4 characters , counting from back.

```
    for name in names:
            name[:-4]
        james
        nancy
        temitope
        bianca
```

For more on readlines(), see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

For more on generators, see
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

There is no need to loop the values into the dataframe. Lets go back to the list of names,

```
list_of_names = [name1,name2,name3]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_names,columns={'company_names'})
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more, e.g. why using `strip()` here is not working.

Comment: Thanks EM28 - I always get confused between read() and readline(). I cleaned up per your suggestion and am getting the following error, I think from the to_excel code... not sure what to make of it, as that part was functinoing before:  File "/Users/michaelheitz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MyPharma'

Comment: from what I can determine, the error is coming from the pd.read_excel line:  vendors = pd.read_excel(company, header = 5, skiprows =0-4)

Comment: ok - I see the issue... stripping the xls when we are, is causing us to try and open the filename without the xls extension... I am thinking this might be easier using os instead of having the filenames stored in a txt file... I'll attack it from that angle

Comment: I just edited my code above - i appreciate your help, I know this will click soon on what I am doing wrong... I think I need a loop because I have to open 86 spreadsheets, clean out the first 4 rows of nonsense data, add the column for Company_Name, and populate with the company name that corresponds with the filename. I don't know how else I would do that without a loop of some kind. :( it's now giving me this error - ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

Comment: 1. How many columns does each spreadsheet have? We need to read them, edit them and then append/concat them to a single df. I assume a single column called "company". Confirm.

Comment: we don't need a single data frame - we are just cleaning the excel files, then using SSIS to push up to tables in a SQL server.  Each spreadsheet will have 15 columns including the one I am trying to add. hahaha, I thought it'd be a little easier than it is turning out to be, but I feel I am right on the edge of my EUREKA moment... lol

Comment: When you declare skiprows=2 ,or header=2, the file slices out the first 3 rows and the third row becomes the header. So read the file like this,

Comment: pd.read_excel("f.xlsx", skiprows=3 , names=[list of names for new header]

Comment: You should not combine skiprows with header and the skiprows takes an integer not a range.

Answer (score 0):

again, thanks for your help... amazing what a good night's sleep and some coffee will do for your state of mind. I realized this morning that I was doing too much. I only needed ONE list, not two - to iterate through.  ;)  I'll post my final code above - the only thing I still need to resolve is the leading column it is inserting with the index #'s, but that should be an easy fix - at least I can get through the 86 excel files though!